# Sort floating-point numbers in batch

Tags: string, sorting, batch-file

Hello StackExchange community!

I am trying to solve the problem of sorting floating-point values with batch.

To the point. I have a log file (INPUT.txt) in the following form:

```
889.W_1.153,46
889.W_1.37,43
889.W_1.28,81
889.W_1.34,70
155.W_2.22,67
155.W_2.108,06
155.W_2.22,11
155 W_2 22,65
```

I want to sort this by 1st and 3rd column. I want output (OUTPUT.txt) in this form:

```
155.W_2.22,11
155.W_2.22,65
155.W_2.22,67
155.W_2.108,06
889.W_1.28,81
889.W_1.34,70
889.W_1.37,43
889.W_1.153,46
```

I wrote a small script and it works almost good because my result is:

```
155 108,06 W_2
155 22,11 W_2
155 22,65 W_2
155 22,67 W_2
889 153,46 W_1
889 28,81 W_1
889 34,70 W_1
889 37,43 W_1
```

Dots and column order are not so important, actual problem is with numbers longer than 2 digits. A comma is treated as a " higher " than the number . Below is the script :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%a in (INPUT.txt) do set "a[%%a %%c ]=%%b"
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=[.]=" %%a in ('set a[') do echo %%a%%c%%b>> OUTPUT.txt
```

Correct sorting is not everything I need. I would also have the ability (later in the script) to delete a whole row in which the number is longer than 2 digits in this case it will be row with `153,49` and `108,06`. Any help would be very valuable to me .

Comment: In the last line of your `INPUT.txt` data sample there are no dots `.` (`155 W_2 22,65`); I assume this is a typo, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numeric sorting is not supported by pure batch programs and need to be worked around. The best method is to pad numbers with zeros and do native alphabetic sorting then.

To actually sort, you can use `set` as you already did in your script. Here is a batch file which features the said zero-padding:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "FILE=%~1" & rem // (1st command line argument: file to process)
set "RTNF=%~2" & rem // (2nd command line argument: file to store result)
set /A DIGS=4  & rem // (total number of digits for zero-padding)
set /A DLIM=2  & rem // (maximum number of digits for 3rd field in file)

if not defined RTNF set "RTNF=con"
for /F "eol== delims==" %%V in ('2^> nul set ARRAY[') do set "%%V="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "PAD=" & for /L %%D in (1,1,%DIGS%) do set "PAD=!PAD!0"
endlocal & set "PAD=%PAD%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("!FILE!") do (
    endlocal
    for /F "eol=. tokens=1,3,4 delims=., " %%A in ("%%L") do (
        set "FIELD1=%PAD%%%A"
        set "FIELD3=%%B"
        set "FIELD4=%%C%PAD%"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if "!FIELD3:~%DLIM%!"=="" (
            set "FIELD3=%PAD%!FIELD3!"
            for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%T in ("!FIELD1:~-%DIGS%!.!FIELD3:~-%DIGS%!,!FIELD4:~,4!") do (
                endlocal
                set "ARRAY[%%T]=%%L"
            )
        ) else (
            endlocal
        )
    )
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
)
> "!RTNF!" (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims== eol==" %%I in ('set ARRAY[') do (
        endlocal
        echo(%%I
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
)
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```

For sorting, a pseudo-array variable `ARRAY` is used, whose indexes contain the zero-padded numbers of the applicable fields for sorting, the values are the original lines of the input file:

> ```
> ARRAY[0155.0022,1100]=155.W_2.22,11
> ARRAY[0155.0022,6500]=155 W_2 22,65
> ARRAY[0155.0022,6700]=155.W_2.22,67
> ARRAY[0889.0028,8100]=889.W_1.28,81
> ARRAY[0889.0034,7000]=889.W_1.34,70
> ARRAY[0889.0037,4300]=889.W_1.37,43
> ```

---

Here is another approach using a temporary file and the `sort` command to do the sorting. This is more generic as it does not fail on special characters, like `=` for instance, which adversely impacts the method based on the `set` command. This is the code:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "FILE=%~1" & rem // (1st command line argument: file to process)
set "RTNF=%~2" & rem // (2nd command line argument: file to store result)
set /A DIGS=4  & rem // (total number of digits for zero-padding)
set /A DLIM=2  & rem // (maximum number of digits for 3rd field in file)
set "TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"

if not defined RTNF set "RTNF=con"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "PAD=" & for /L %%D in (1,1,%DIGS%) do set "PAD=!PAD!0"
endlocal & set "PAD=%PAD%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
> "!TMPF!" (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("!FILE!") do (
        endlocal
        set "LINE=%%L"
        for /F "eol=. tokens=1,3,4 delims=., " %%A in ("%%L") do (
            set "FIELD1=%PAD%%%A"
            set "FIELD3=%%B"
            set "FIELD4=%%C%PAD%"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            if "!FIELD3:~%DLIM%!"=="" (
                set "FIELD3=%PAD%!FIELD3!"
                echo(!FIELD1:~-%DIGS%!.!FIELD3:~-%DIGS%!,!FIELD4:~,4!^|!LINE!
            )
            endlocal
        )
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
)
> "!RTNF!" (
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('sort "!TMPF!"') do (
        endlocal
        set "LINE=%%I"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!LINE:*^|=!
    )
)
del "!TMPF!"
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```

The temporary file used for sorting contains the zero-padded numbers of the applicable fields for sorting, a predefined separator `|` and the original lines of the input file:

> ```
> 0889.0037,4300|889.W_1.37,43
> 0889.0028,8100|889.W_1.28,81
> 0889.0034,7000|889.W_1.34,70
> 0155.0022,6700|155.W_2.22,67
> 0155.0022,1100|155.W_2.22,11
> 0155.0022,6500|155 W_2 22,65
> ```

Comment: That was the code I feared was necessary ;-) Nicely done (also that's an evil trick of abusing `set` for sorting :D).

Answer (score 0):

Your code just required a small adjustment:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=.," %%a in (INPUT.txt) do (
   set /A "first=1000+%%a,third=100000+%%c%%d"
   set "a[!first!!third!]=%%a.%%b.%%c,%%d"
)

(for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set a[') do echo %%a) > OUTPUT.txt
```